# How to prevent Realm from overwriting itself while parsing JSON to a Realm database in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm, urlsession

I've got a problem with Realm. I want to write an external JSON script to my Realm database with Swift. But when doing that it overwrites the record in my database every loop. When I print the class `print(songClass)` it shows it correctly but when doing this

```
class SongR: Object {

    @objc dynamic var id: String?
    @objc dynamic var rawName: String?
    @objc dynamic var title: String?
    @objc dynamic var artist: String?
    @objc dynamic var album: String?
    @objc dynamic var playlist: String?
    @objc dynamic var link: String?

}


let realm = try! Realm()

let songClass = SongR()


if let url = URL(string: "http://somewebsite.com/json.php") {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                if let data = data {
                    let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                    do {
                        let parsedJSON = try jsonDecoder.decode([Song].self, from: data)
                        let main = DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            try! realm.write {
                                for song in parsedJSON {
                                    songClass.id = song.id
                                    songClass.rawName = song.rawName
                                    songClass.title = song.title
                                    songClass.artist = song.artist
                                    songClass.album = song.album
                                    songClass.playlist = song.playlist
                                    songClass.link = song.link
                                    realm.add(songClass)
                                    print(songClass)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }.resume()
        }
```

it overwrites itself and I only get the last value from the JSON file displayed in my Realm database.

Anyone got a clue how to fix this?

Also, I want to overwrite the whole Realm database with all the items from the JSON file every time I parse/update the JSON file and not add them to it. How do I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. `let songClass = SongR()` needed to be inside the loop:

```
let main = DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            try! realm.write {
                                for song in parsedJSON {
                                    let songClass = SongR()
                                    songClass.id = song.id
                                    songClass.rawName = song.rawName
                                    songClass.title = song.title
                                    songClass.artist = song.artist
                                    songClass.album = song.album
                                    songClass.playlist = song.playlist
                                    songClass.link = song.link
                                    realm.add(songClass)
                                    print(songClass)
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: Correct. Each separate song object needs to be created and populated each time through the loop - good job on the solution. This question doesn't address the second part of your question about overwriting the whole database as this code will continually add new objects.

Comment: @Jay I got the second solution as well but it's not good for large databases. For now it will do while I debug everything. I call this in viewDidLoad: 

`func deleteAllRealm() {
        try! realm.write {
            realm.deleteAll()
        }
    }
`

I think later I would need to update rows by individual IDs but I got much more to do at the moment, that can wait. If you have an idea I would love to hear it. :)

Comment: Add what you posted in you comment in the answer. Code in comments is hard to read. Also, why is deleteAll not good for large databases? It works for any size database.